# testing concurrency locally

Tags: java, testing, concurrency

An issue popped up, which we have not been able to pin down. It's looking like a concurrency issue with a shared singleton bean, but that is just the hypothesis.

I need a way to recreate this error locally. It only surfaced when two threads processed together at the same thousandth of a second. I'm wondering is there a way to test this locally without having to fish through in debug mode.

Our process is simple enough.

It obtains an object from a topic processes and enriches then send new object to be published to a topic. We have two listener threads.

Tech used

- IDE eclipse
- ldap topics
- Code Java/Spring

Comment: Which technology/languages are you using?

Comment: added I can go into further detail if required

Comment: Advanced thread debuggers can be of great use here since they can record and replay the context switching. The [master thesis of Satyavathi Malladi](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.7449&rep=rep1&type=pdf) gives a nice overview for C-style languages. I can't give you a hint for Java, sorry, but I'm sure there are similar debuggers.

Answer (score 0):

too few details to give precise answer. i would refactor the code so all the synchronization code was separated from business logic. then, during tests, you can replace your business logic with a code that invokes `yeld()` method and uses volatile/atomic variables to check if at this point of code and at this specific time there are expected number of threads. then use any concurrent testing framework (i like multithreadedtc). below you can find piority queue implementation i used to test my algorithm that supposed to do concurrent operation on queues

```
class YeldingHeap implements PriorityQueue<Integer> {

private AtomicInteger concurrentReads = new AtomicInteger();
private AtomicInteger concurrentWrites = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public int size() {
    read();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void insert(Integer element) {
    write();
}

@Override
public Integer popMax() {
    write();
    return null;
}

private void write() {
    int writes = concurrentWrites.incrementAndGet();
    int reads = concurrentReads.incrementAndGet();
    assertEquals(writes, 1, "more than 1 thread is writing");
    assertEquals(reads, 1, "other thread is reading while this thread is writing");
    Thread.yield();
    writes = concurrentWrites.decrementAndGet();
    reads = concurrentReads.decrementAndGet();
    assertEquals(writes, 0, "more than 1 thread is writing");
    assertEquals(reads, 0, "other thread is reading while this thread is writing");
}

private void read() {
    concurrentReads.incrementAndGet();
    int writes = concurrentWrites.get();
    assertEquals(writes, 0, "other thread is writing while this thread is reading");
    Thread.yield();
    writes = concurrentWrites.get();
    assertEquals(writes, 0, "other thread is writing while this thread is reading");
    concurrentReads.decrementAndGet();
}

}
```